# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am getting following error when I am trying to upload image for predictive model.

**Trackback**

File "/Users/ragnar/plant-disease-recognition/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/ragnar/plant-disease-recognition/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/ragnar/plant-disease-recognition/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/ragnar/Downloads/Plant-Diseases-Recognition-master/plant_diseases/plant_app/views.py" in index
12.         img = image.load_img(myfile, target_size=(224, 224))

File "/Users/ragnar/plant-disease-recognition/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py" in load_img
299.   return image.load_img(path, grayscale=grayscale, color_mode=color_mode,

File "/Users/ragnar/plant-disease-recognition/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py" in load_img
113.     with open(path, 'rb') as f:

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

views.py

```
class Predict(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        """
            post:
            API to send leaf image and get its health status or disease.
        """
        data = ImageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if data.is_valid():
            photo = request.data['photo']
            img = image.load_img(photo, target_size=(224, 224))
            img = image.img_to_array(img)
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            img = img/255

            with graph.as_default():
                prediction = model.predict(img)

            prediction_flatten = prediction.flatten()
            max_val_index = np.argmax(prediction_flatten)
            result = output_list[max_val_index]

            return Response({'result': result})
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback, not just one section.

Comment: thank you. I would ask for you to reformat the traceback, but it will not allow you to as it will give you a "This post is mostly code" error.

Comment: Try `image.load_img(photo.read(), target_size=(224, 224))`

Comment: **image.load_img(photo.read(), target_size=(224, 224))** is throwing another error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b''